# Vue - How to avoid a content flash before Vue loads

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I see my header and footer, which are outside router-view flash for a few ms before vue is loaded and a loader is applied to the page (see gif). How do I avoid this behavior and straight away show a loader?

I am using v-cloak but it doesn't seem to work.

[image]

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div 
    id="cq-app"
    @click="handleClicks">
    <div v-cloak style="min-height:100vh;">
      <header-main />

      <transition
        name="fade"
        mode="out-in"
        @after-leave="updateScroll"
      >
        <router-view :key="$route.path" />
      </transition>

      <transition name="fade">
        <site-loading v-if="loading" />
      </transition>

      <footer-main />
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SiteLoading from '@/components/utility/SiteLoading'
import HeaderMain from '@/components/utility/HeaderMain'
import FooterMain from '@/components/utility/FooterMain'

export default {
  components: {
    SiteLoading,
    HeaderMain,
    FooterMain
  },
  data() {
    return {
      site: this.$store.state.site
    }
  },
  computed: {
    loading() {
      return this.$store.state.site.loading
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getLinkEl(el) {
      while (el.parentNode) {
        if (el.tagName === 'A') return el
        el = el.parentNode
      }
    },
    handleClicks (e) {

    },
    updateScroll() {
      window.scroll(0,0)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you included the CSS for `v-cloak`?

Comment: Yes I have - ```[v-cloak] { display: none; }```

Comment: v-cloak is applied until the template is compiled and has no knowledge of `loading` so it's more than likely working correctly.  Why not add `v-show="!loading"` to the header and footer.

Comment: Yeah, having `v-cloak` in a template is meaningless as it's intended to hide content before Vue starts. It only makes sense directly in the HTML file and isn't relevant here. My guess would be that the problem is either the transition on `site-loading` (verify that by disabling it) or there's a delay in starting to load the data (you may want to consider setting `loading` to `false` initially, at least to see what happens).

Comment: So the delay in loading was because `loading` was set to `false` initially. Changing it to 'true' and removing transition from `site-loading` solved the issue. @skirtle thank you!